# Do not cache custom block

Tags: 7, caching

I have a custom block created in code. I do not want to cache the block. I know I need to use BLOCK_NO_CACHE but I am not sure where to use it.

```
function mymod_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0)
{
    // set up an empty array which will contain the block contents
    $block = array();
    if ($op == "list") {
        // Generate listing of blocks from this module, for the admin/block page
        $block[0]["info"] = t('mymod');
    }
    else if ($op == 'view') {        
        $block['content'] = "hello world";
    }
    // return the built content
    return $block;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your list $op, add:

```
$block[0]['cache'] = BLOCK_NO_CACHE;
```

However, note that Drupal 6 will not automatically update your block information, you will have to do that yourself, see [privatemsg_update_6002()](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/privatemsg/privatemsg.install/function/privatemsg_update_6002/1) for an example.

Comment: to note: "If page cache is enabled then blocks *will* be cached, regardless of block cache settings in hook_block()." -- http://www.drupaler.co.uk/blog/page-and-block-caching/114